# Error to set image to UIImageView at TableViewCell on Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

I want to set an Image to my `UIImageView`, I did tried two ways: Set image on attributes inspector and programmatically, but nothing works. 
I don't know if the image needs pre size before copy to Assets folder on project.

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerListaObjetos: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewItens: UITableView!
var titlePage : String?
var listaDados : [[String:Any]] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.title = titlePage!
    self.tableViewItens.delegate = self
    self.tableViewItens.dataSource = self
    print("ViewDidLoad ViewControllerObjects")
    switch (titlePage!) {
    case "Produtos":
        print("Titulo -> Produtos")
        let lista = SQLite.readAll(tabela: Utils.dictDadoTabela[titlePage!]!, typeClass: Product.self)

        if lista.count > 0 {
            listaDados.append((lista.first?.attributes)!)
            lista.first?.toString()
        }
        break

    case "Vendas":
        print("Titulo -> Vendas")
        let lista = SQLite.readAll(tabela: Utils.dictDadoTabela[titlePage!]!, typeClass: SaleOrder.self)
        if lista.count > 0 {
            lista.first?.toString()
        }
        break

    case "Clientes":
        print("Titulo -> Clientes")
        let lista = SQLite.readAll(tabela: Utils.dictDadoTabela[titlePage!]!, typeClass: ResPartner.self)
        if lista.count > 0 {
            lista.first?.toString()
        }
        break

    case "Itens de Vendas":
        print("Titulo -> Itens de Vendas")
        let lista = SQLite.readAll(tabela: Utils.dictDadoTabela[titlePage!]!, typeClass: SaleOrderLine.self)
        if lista.count > 0 {
            lista.first?.toString()
        }
        break

    default:
        print("Nenhum tipo encontrado.")
        break
    }

    tableViewItens.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listaDados.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()

    switch (titlePage!) {

    case "Produtos":
        print("Title = Produtos")
        cell = getCellProduct(index: indexPath.row, tableView)!
        break

    case "Clientes":

        break

    default:
        print("Nao encontrou titulo da pagina certo!")
        break
    }

    return cell
}

// Carregar dados conforme tipo
func getCellProduct(index: Int, _ tableView: UITableView) -> TableViewCellProduct? {
    if let cell = self.tableViewItens.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 1)) as? TableViewCellProduct {
        cell.imageProduct.image = UIImage(named: "produto.jpg")
        return cell
    }
    return nil
}

    func getCellResPartner() -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}
```

I receive the error:

```
2018-04-12 10:45:36.295610-0300 Odoo_01[26861:981455] -[UIImageView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fab9b547d40
2018-04-12 10:45:36.305878-0300 Odoo_01[26861:981455] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fab9b547d40'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113b1412b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011033df41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113b95024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000110e0df51 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 295
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113a96f78 ___forwarding___ + 1432
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113a96958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001115d55ad -[UIImageView(Pretiling) _updatePretiledImageCacheForImage:] + 78
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000110e0aed1 -[UIImageView _updateImageViewForOldImage:newImage:] + 369
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000110e05e86 -[UIImageView setImage:] + 390
    9   UIKit                               0x000000011101148c -[UITableViewCell setImage:] + 79
    10  Foundation                          0x000000010fd5ca63 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000110cab288 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 172
    12  UIKit                               0x000000011106bc2d -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113ab73cd -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 317
    14  UIKit                               0x000000011106a5e3 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000110d1f687 -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:] + 590
    16  Odoo_01                             0x000000010f5f7576 _T07Odoo_0126ViewControllerListaObjetosC14getCellProductAA05TablebgH0CSgSi5index_So07UITableB0CtF + 150
    17  Odoo_01                             0x000000010f5f6d34 _T07Odoo_0126ViewControllerListaObjetosC05tableB0So07UITableB4CellCSo0gB0C_10Foundation9IndexPathV12cellForRowAttF + 1780
    18  Odoo_01                             0x000000010f5f74bc _T07Odoo_0126ViewControllerListaObjetosC05tableB0So07UITableB4CellCSo0gB0C_10Foundation9IndexPathV12cellForRowAttFTo + 92
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000110d3b484 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 778
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000110d3ba2a -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000110d011f6 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3031
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000110d232e6 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 176
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000110caba6d -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1439
    24  QuartzCore                          0x000000011a52461c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 159
    25  QuartzCore                          0x000000011a5287ad _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 401
    26  QuartzCore                          0x000000011a4af86c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 364
    27  QuartzCore                          0x000000011a4dc946 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 500
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000110c04167 _afterCACommitHandler + 272
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113ab6c07 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113ab6b5e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113a9b124 __CFRunLoopRun + 1572
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000113a9a889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    33  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001190459c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    34  UIKit                               0x0000000110bda5d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    35  Odoo_01                             0x000000010f60d637 main + 55
    36  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000115371d81 start + 1
    37  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I load image on Assests. And configure in my storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Remove screenshot add code and error message

Comment: I think you accidentally cut the IBOutlet

Comment: this is not set an Image in UIImageView. you remove a IBOutlet or IBAction but not delete from xcode its reference available in storyboard.

Comment: First check all possibilities
1. Check IBOutlet is properly set or not
2. Is your image saved in asset with name "produco"(don't add extension)
3. Added all size images in your "produco" image set

Comment: I add the code and remove screenshoot

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the cell, no dequeueCell in that method, using `self.tableView.cellForRow(at: desiredIndexPath)` you can get your cell

```
func getCellProduct(index:Int,tableView:UITableView) ->TableViewCellProduct? {
  if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at:  NSIndexPath(row: index, section: 0)) as? TableViewCellProduct {
     cell.imageProduct.image = UIImage(named:"producto")
     return cell
  } 
  return nil
}
```

Comment: this only returns nil to me.

Comment: check the indexpath your table have only one section @Augusto

Comment: Keeping return nil...
`    func getCellProduct(index: Int, _ tableView: UITableView) -> TableViewCellProduct? {
        if let cell = self.tableViewItens.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 1)) as? TableViewCellProduct {
            cell.imageProduct.image = UIImage(named: "produto.jpg")
            return cell
        }
        return nil
    }`

Comment: You are trying to instanciate your cells with that method? @Augusto why you need that?

Comment: @Augusto please explain me a little bit more about what are you trying I can help you

Comment: Of course, I have 3 itens in my database, Product, Customer and Sale. I have a list with 3 itens, and when I choose one, I go to view controller with a table view to show the content of the option, at this time I try make this with only product. But each item, have a different cell view. For this, when the view controller has loaded, I need know which options has selected, and make the correct custom cell, I have one custom cell to product, one to customer and one to sale, but one tableview.